# Android Link Error Web page not available asp .net

Tags: .net, asp.net, android, hyperlink

My app is an asp .net vb app.  The link appears to work in any browser...except Android.

Here is the dynamic link:  http://rentonlive.com/TandL.aspx?xid=106&xtitle=RED%LIGHT%CAMERAS%READER%SURVEY

What is Android looking for?  If this is a basic question that I could have figured out elsewhere please guide me after you help me with this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what actually happens? When you say it fails in the Android browser, how are you opening the URL in the browser?

Comment: I get the Page Not Found error.

Comment: ...I'm clicking on a hyperlink object to get to that page fro my main page:  http://www.rentonlive.com

Comment: Clicking on a hyperlink object where? On a web page? In the Android app? If in the app, how are you showing the link? Is the phone connected to the network? If you don't provide specifics about the issue, no-one can help you. The page works fine, so the way you are passing the link to the Android browser is not working.

Comment: I provided the link to my main page so you could see it works fine IE, FF, etc.  Ope the same window in any android based browser and clicking on the link on my article, again the link given above, but choose the RED LIGHT CAMERAS article or any of the article links as a test and it errors.  Discoverd the problem with Nook device which is a large enough screen that it opens the normal large page at rentonlive.com and does not forward it to the smaller device pages which opens mini version.  Either results in the same problem when you click on a hyperlink which is what my article titles are...

Comment: The only browser I know of where the hyperlinks to my articles do not work is the Android browser.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this in the Dolphin browser on Android and that link opens fine. I see a survey relating to red lights. This may therefore be an issue with the specific Android device you tested on, but I think both the cause and the fix are under your control.

Certainly one big problem here is the URL format. Your URL query string parameter xtitle is set to a string that contains % characters. The % character has a special meaning in URLs, it means the following two characters form a HEX character code. So for example if you had xtitle=cat%20and%20dog that sets the xtitle string to "cat and dog" because %20 is the hex encoding for a space character (ASCII character 20).

Your URL is invalid and does not conform the the RFC definition, so it is not reasonable to expect it to work across all browser. I am surprised it works at all in any browser as it completely is wrong - you cannot put any string into a URL parameter, it must be processed first.

You need to properly encode your query string parameters before you add them to the URL string. There is a method in ASP.NET to URL encode a string before you add it to a parameter.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

For more information about the URL standard look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator

Please rate all answers to questions you post on here, and select the answer you like best with the tick.

Comment: Yes, perfect, it was the %.  It's worked so long with all the other browsers I never questioned it.

Comment: @Brian If my answer is satisfactory, remember to select it and vote on it. You also get points on Stackoverflow by doing this.

Comment: FWIW the other short cut for spaces in query params in ASP.NET is + so if your url would have xtitle=cat+dog+bob that would be good too.