# Android Does Not Process my Hyperlinks ASP .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, android

See http://www.rentonlive.com   Click on any article title.  Hyperlinks work for every browser.

Android is not allowing this simple hyperlink:  http://rentonlive.com/TandL.aspx?xid=106&xtitle=RED%LIGHT%CAMERAS%READER%SURVEY

I get a web page not found error.

Is there something wrong with the construction of the link in terms of Android?

I downloaded an emulator, same problem.  The phone says it has a browser, finding the 'rules' to this 'browser' is very difficult.  And, all works fine in Google Chrome.

Any pointers or sites that provide answers to Android issues appreciated.

Comment: ... to be absolutely precise, the message is "Web page is not available"  The web page at http://rentonlive.com/minimenews.aspx?xid=106&title etc., same link as above.

Comment: If I type the text rentonlive.com/minimenews.aspx?xid=106  and nothing more the bookmark at least opens the page correctly.

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927158/android-link-error-web-page-not-available-asp-net?

Answer (score 1):

The `%` character is a special character in URLs.  It is actually the escape character used for special characters (like `&` in HTML).  It seems plausible that some browsers would misbehave when seeing `&xtitle=RED%LIGHT%CAMERAS%READER%SURVEY`.   (I tried accessing your site, but was unable to connect to it from any browser.)